# Variables in .h-file as opposed to .m-file in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I fairly new to IOS programming, and came over this the other day:

say you have a TestVC.h file:

```
@interface TestVC : UIViewController 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress;
@end
```

and in TestVC.m file (at the top):

```
@interface TestVC ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *levels;
@end
```

When you use a variable from .h-file, you'd say `self.progress`

If you use a variable from the .m-file, it's `_levels`

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you use a variable from .h-file, you'd say self.progress
>
> If you use a variable from the .m-file, it's _levels

There is no difference. `self.progress` and `_progress` and `self.levels` and `_levels` are all perfectly functional.

However, the `_` syntax is a *tiny* bit faster and the `self.` syntax is the proper way to do it except in a few cases where it's not. There are times when using `_` will cause serious problems that are solved by using `self.`. And there are times when `self.` will cause problems.

Basically `_` is accessing the raw memory address directly, and `self.` is accessing it "properly" using the objective-c language.

The difference between declaring a variable in *.m vs *.h is that the one in *.m is hidden, so nothing else in your source code can see that it exists. It is there but you will get a compiler warning that it doesn't exist. When it compiles it will work though, because really it does exist.

Basically declaring variables in *.m is a way of saying "this thing is here but I don't want anything outside this file to ever use it". It's purely cosmetic, has no impact on the how the app functions.

As a new Obj-C programmer, you should always use `self.levels`. Any time you see sample code using `_levels` I would change it to `self.levels`. If you run into problems... ask here to see if you've found a case where `_levels` should be used.

Comment: -Basically declaring variables in *.m is a way of saying "this thing is here but I don't want anything outside this file to ever use it"

So it's basically a way to make variables/functions private?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same as making it private except it doesn't actually make it private. Note that iOS does support proper formal private properties, but in general Obj-C programmers prefer to do things by convention rather than with language restrictions. For example, making a method pseudo private instead of actually private means you can access it from unit tests or from a second class that is part of another class that is a companion class. A proper private property would not allow that flexibility. It's not private, it's just undocumented.

Comment: Obj-C programmers trust the documentation/public API of a class rather than how it's technically implemented. The assumption is the implementation could change at any time (eg, properties declared in *.m could be renamed) but the official ones (anything in *.h) is always going to be around, even if the property is deleted or renamed the old property will still exist as an alias for the new behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

They can be used in either format regardless of their being declared in the .h or .m files.

Best practice is to use the getter/setter  "self." format everywhere with the possible exception of init and dealloc methods where the "_" direct access method is generally deemed to be a better choice.